# Pandas matching elements

Tags: python, pandas

i have a database named df1 and  a sheet named df2。

i want to use df1 filling df2 by pandas。

DF1:

```
    name    SCORE   height  weight  
1   JACK    66      150     100  
2   PAUL    50      165      22  
3   MLKE    30      132      33  
4   Meir    20      110      20  
5   Payne   10      175      21
```

DF2:

```
    name    SCORE   height  weight
1   JACK            
2   PAUL            
3   MLKE
```

***name  maybe  mess up the order**

my misktake code :

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx',sheet_name =0))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('df2.xlsx',sheet_name = 0))

result = df1.merge(df2,on = ['NAME'],how="left")
```

DF1:
[image]

Expected result:

DF2:

```
    name    SCORE   height  weight
1   JACK    66      150     100
2   PAUL    50      165     22
3   MLKE    30      132     33
```

Comment: Can you 1) provide some data that we can easily ingest. 2) provide what your expected output looks like and how it currently looks?

Comment: sorry,I am not very good at English. i Unable to query pandas manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `name` maybe mess up the order, therefore, if you want to use `df1` to fill-up `df2`, you can try setting `name` as index in both `df1` and `df2` and then use [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), as follows:

```
df1a = df1.set_index('name')
df2a = df2.set_index('name')

df2a.update(df1a)
df2 = df2a.reset_index()
```

**Result:**

(Using `df1` data based on the picture near the bottom):

```
print(df2)

   name SCORE height weight
0  JACK    66    150    100
1  PAUL    50    165     22
2  MLKE    30    132     33
```

If you want to keep the original row index of `df2`, you can save the index and then restore it later, as follows:

```
df1a = df1.set_index('name')
df2a = df2.set_index('name')
df2a.update(df1a)

df2_idx = df2.index
df2 = df2a.reset_index()
df2.index = df2_idx
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

   name SCORE height weight
1  JACK    66    150    100
2  PAUL    50    165     22
3  MLKE    30    132     33
```